# How to convert one text to another text in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I need help!
I'm doing this for a chemistry project.

I have to build an app that will convert a compound to an element

Example:
Carbon Monoxide = CO

So if I type "Carbon Monoxide" and click enter it should give me "CO"

I just need the Java code for it thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: I don't think it is categorized at javascript

Answer (score 0):

In Java I would use a HashMap for this.

```
HashMap<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

myMap.put("Carbon Monoxide","CO");
myMap.put("Copper Solfate","CuSO4");

System.out.println(myMap.get("CO"));//prints Carbon Monoxide
```